# How to denormalize data in documents in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic, denormalization, marklogic-9, mlcp

I have a bunch of normalized documents that I've loaded using CSV files in MLCP. How can  I use the primary key (say ID) and locate all the relating documents and merge them into one denormalized document? I also need to change some value in the initial document.

Answer (score 2):

This is a prime use case for MarkLogic's Data Hub Framework (DHF) - https://marklogic.github.io/marklogic-data-hub/ . You'd still ingest the CSV files into MLCP (this would be your "raw" data that goes into a staging database), and then DHF provides some plumbing for writing a "harmonize" flow that would merge all related documents into a single document (and those documents would go into your final database).

You can also achieve this using CoRB - https://developer.marklogic.com/code/corb . DHF is similar to CoRB, but with more plumbing for this sort of use case.

Answer (score 1):

Using a framework like @rjrudin suggests is definitely the way to go for any large job or ongoing process.  However it still helps to experiment to get an idea of what your asking the framework to do. ('GIGO') -- Putting a little human thought and manual effort upfront will pay off bigtime -- 'Denormalizing' is not a purely mechanical/objective process -- its a mix of domain knowledge, creative compromising and targeted data enrichments.

I suggest you start by using the same process you would use for RDBMS schema desgin -- think about queries.  Its useful to get a 'top 10' list from the main users of the data/application for what kinds of queries/questions are going to be needed most and what kinds of results and formats are expected.  Denormalization isnt that useful out of context -- (an extreme example would be simply to put ALL data in a single 'denormalized' document'  -- probably not useful).

A simplististic but useful concept is that MarkLogic works very well for 'Document' based  questions and answers.  "Think Like Google".  When you use google what are you looking for ? Are you looking for web sites? or distilled concise 'facts'?  Aggreations/statistics ?   If your queries are largely of the sort "Give me all the documents that have information about XYZ"  then you will likely want to denormalize into documents which are centered around topics of the "XYZ" sort.  If your domain has a natural document centric grouping of information (say a pharmaceutical company has 'Drug' related documents, a travel company has 'Property' related documents). 
Very important to keep in mind that both searching and document creation/update operate at the 'Document' level -- and then let your anticipated queries and result sets guide your definition of "Document" rather than create documents based solely on foreign key 
relationships extracted from the normalized views.   In the classic 'Business Documents' 
example -- if your business domain has workflows centered on "Invoices" and "Purchase Orders" then it makes sense to make each Invoice a seperate document, possibly embedding all the line item details within it.   However it your business workflows are focused on inventory management it may make more sense to model documents on each inventory part, possibly with order details embedded within each part -- or both.

The mechanics of denormalization are quite simple once you have decided on your document model -- it is almost identical to a RDBMS Join query -- except you dont have to create fixed 'rows' and 'columns'.    XQuery, inside of QConsole is a good platform for experimenting with your document model.  Then when you have it close, transitioning to one of the frameworks described should be easy.

A rough example of an Order/Item document denormalizaiton might look like this: (pseudo code)

```
for $order in /order_recored_csv/order
let $doc :=  <order> {
  $order/*,

  for $line_item in /item_record_csv/line_item[ order_id = $order/order_id ]
  return   
       <line>{ $line_item/* except $line_item/order_id }</line>
   }
  </order>
return xdmp:document-insert( "/orders/{$doc/order_id}" , $doc )
```

Which would create a set of "order" documents with their associated line items in each.

You may then want to improve with say adding customer information, data enrichment (translating ID's to values, looking up data from external sources, assigning unique identifiers, versioning, data origin references etc).